# Symfony2 app in subdirectory of nginx configuration

Tags: nginx, virtualhost, symfony

I'm trying to set up my environment such that `surveyadmin.local` points at one directory and `surveyadmin.local/api` points at another.

However, no matter what I change, the `/api` URL always results in a call to the directory that `surveyadmin.local` is pointing at. Here's a sample error from the error log specified in the vhost config:

```
2013/08/09 17:20:07 [error] 8911#0: *1 open() "/srv/http/surveytool/admin/build/app.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.0.2.2, server: surveyadmin.local, request: "GET /api/organizations HTTP/1.1", host: "surveyadmin.local"
```

Note that the error refers to a path of `/srv/http/surveytool/admin/buid/`, instead of the `/srv/http/surveytool/api/SurveyTool/web/` that was expected.

Here's my config for the vhost in question:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name surveyadmin.local;

    location / {
        root /srv/http/surveytool/admin/build;
        index index.html;
    }

    location /api {
        root /srv/http/surveytool/api/SurveyTool/web;
        index app.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /app.php?$query_String;
        location ~ \.php(?|$) {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index app.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/surveyadmin.access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/surveyadmin.error.log debug;
}
```

I have tried changing the word "root" to "alias" under the `location /api` block. I've tried setting up a second virtual host and doing a proxy forward (with `proxy_pass`) to that vhost.

This seems like it shouldn't be that difficult, so I'm assuming my error is a simple one that I just haven't seen yet.

Can anyone spot any obvious problems with the above config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `root` inside `location` blocks. This is one of the [most common nginx misconfigurations](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/).

Instead, place the `root` in the `server` block, and use [`alias`](http://nginx.org/r/alias) inside `location` blocks that need specific directories outside the normal document root.

Comment: Aye, I've done that now, and it's looking in the right directory this time. However, it seems to be ignoring the try_files directive (which I've also moved outside of the location and into the server block).

A request for `/api/organizations` should be served by `app.php?querystring`, but the error I get back implies that it's looking for a file called organizations.

Comment: That sounds like a separate issue.